# Unable to convert the CStringW to CStringA

Tags: c++, string, mfc, cstring, mbcs

I am working on one project where I have stucked on one problem of converting `CStringW` to `CStringA` for multibyte string like Japanese Language.

I am loading the string from string resources using `LoadString()` Method.
I have tried  following code but it does not seem to work.

```
CStringW csTest;
csTest.LoadString(JAPANESE_STRING);
CStringA Msg = CStringA(csTest); // Msg has been returned blank string
```

And

```
std::string Msg = CW2A(csTest);// Msg has been returned blank string
```

I have also tried 
`wcstombs()` too.

Can anyone tell me how I can convert `CStringW` to `CString`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shame that this question doesn't pop up when people ask for `CString` wide to `char*`. The transition by CStringA is more straightforward and manageable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CStringW` stores **Unicode UTF-16** strings.

What **encoding** do you expect for your `CStringA`?

Do you want **UTF-8**?
In this case, you can do:

```
// strUtf16 is a CStringW.
// Convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8
CStringA strUtf8 = CW2A(strUtf16, CP_UTF8);
```

Talking about `CStringA` without specifying an encoding doesn't make sense.

The second parameter of `CW2A` is a what is passed to [`WideCharToMultiByte()` Win32 API as `CodePage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) (note that `CW2A` is essentially a convenient safe C++ RAII wrapper around this API). If you follow this API documentation, you can find [several *"code page"* values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) (i.e. encodings).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But It is not working I am getting Garbage Values after using statement `CStringA strUtf8 = CW2A(strUtf16, CP_UTF8);`

Comment: You get "garbage values" probably because you are not expecting UTF-8 bytes in the destination `CStringA`?

Comment: So what would be the best practice to get the desired output?

Comment: The "best practice" would be that you clarify to yourself and in your question _what encoding_ you expect as _"the desidered output"_, and specify the proper "code page" value accordingly.

Comment: Thanks It works sorry for my mistake I was using wrong Code Page